# Check for field name exists in AWS OpenSearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I want to check whether the field exists in the index of OpenSearch or not. I expect the response should be in Boolean 'True' Or 'False'.

In Elasticsearch to check index exists or not, we use the following code

```
if es.indices.exists(index="index"):
```

Is there any function/logic to check for field names present in the AWS OpenSearch index? If the field does not exist, then I have to return  the response as "Field not found in the index"

My Sample Code:

```
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection, AWSV4SignerAuth
import boto3

host = 'my-test-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com' 
region = 'us-east-1' 

credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
auth = AWSV4SignerAuth(credentials, region)
index_name = 'movies'

client = OpenSearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = auth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

q = 'miller'
query = {
  'size': 5,
  'query': {
    'multi_match': {
      'query': q,
      'fields': ['title^2', 'director']
    }
  }
}

response = client.search(
    body = query,
    index = index_name
)

print('\nSearch results:')
print(response)
```

Comment: Are you using the Python SDK? We need more info; OpenSearch is based on ElasticSearch so the same code *should* work.

Comment: I want to implement it in my python code. I am using  opensearch-py client for Python.